# How to get userinfo in springboot using keycloak?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak, keycloak-services

I was able to get the username by using:

```
@Autowired
 private HttpServletRequest request;
 Principal user = request.getUserPrincipal();
 mqMessage.setUserName(user.getName());
```

But I want to get the firstName & lastName of the user logged in.
How can i get the ff. userinfo using SpringBoot keycloak adapter?

Answer (score 11):

```
        KeycloakAuthenticationToken token = (KeycloakAuthenticationToken) request.getUserPrincipal();        
        KeycloakPrincipal principal=(KeycloakPrincipal)token.getPrincipal();
        KeycloakSecurityContext session = principal.getKeycloakSecurityContext();
        AccessToken accessToken = session.getToken();
        username = accessToken.getPreferredUsername();
        emailID = accessToken.getEmail();
        lastname = accessToken.getFamilyName();
        firstname = accessToken.getGivenName();
        realmName = accessToken.getIssuer();            
        Access realmAccess = accessToken.getRealmAccess();
        roles = realmAccess.getRoles();
```

You can make use of the above code snippet to get the first and the last name
This is from **2.4.0**

Answer (score 7):

Implemented with Keycloak 11 and Spring security

More references: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_spring_security_adapter

```
import java.security.Principal;
/** More imports */

@GetMapping("/userinfo")
public String userInfoController(Model model, Principal principal) {

        KeycloakAuthenticationToken keycloakAuthenticationToken = (KeycloakAuthenticationToken) principal;
        AccessToken accessToken = keycloakAuthenticationToken.getAccount().getKeycloakSecurityContext().getToken();

        model.addAttribute("username", accessToken.getGivenName());
        return "page";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we can use SecurityContextHolder for getting user details.

```
 Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    KeycloakPrincipal principal = (KeycloakPrincipal)auth.getPrincipal();


    KeycloakSecurityContext session = principal.getKeycloakSecurityContext();
    AccessToken accessToken = session.getToken();
    String username = accessToken.getPreferredUsername();
    String emailID = accessToken.getEmail();
    String lastname = accessToken.getFamilyName();
    String firstname = accessToken.getGivenName();
    String realmName = accessToken.getIssuer();
    AccessToken.Access realmAccess = accessToken.getRealmAccess();
```

Comment: auth is always null for me

Comment: @YamenNassif you must be authenticated for getting `Authentication` from `SecurityContextHolder`. Maybe check your spring security config?